# DD-WRT: Router assigns a dynamic IP in addition to a static IP causing systems to get two IP addresses

Tags: dd-wrt

I have my server in my room right now because my WiFi card doesn't support AP mode and I need to bridge a VM to the local network.

I opted to start simple. I used my WNDR3400 with DD-WRT and put all my devices on that.
I have my Kubuntu server with a windows 7kvm plugged in via ethernet.
I gave kubuntu a static ip of 192.168.1.110 and Windows 7 a static ip of 192.168.1.111.

I declared this in the Services menu of DD-WRT. And I declared .110 in kubuntu's network settings menu on a new ethernet connection.
Everything worked great! I could ssh and rdp through my forwarded ports and everything.

Cool, now to add the 2nd router. I plug kubuntu into the 2nd router, disconnect my old connction (rt1) and created a new one (rtSetup) with a static ip of 192.168.1.140 (the 2nd router's local ip is 192.168.1.100)

I setup the router with the wifi info and set it to bridge more and then turned it off.

I plugged kubuntu back into the the original router, I did this because when i turn the 2nd router back on I want to see if I can ping it from the gateway router.

And then problems started, I couldn't get on the web even though I had an ip address or 192.168.1.110. I looked in the menu and I see two active devices with the same MAC address.
Kubuntu was given two ips, the one it declared and the one DHCP gave it .127.

If I set Kubuntu to use DHCP I get .127 and get get online. It will ignore the static assignment on the router. If I request .110 in Kubuntu wierd things happen, I get two connections with two different interfaces for connection rt1.
I will get (rt1 (enpl0s) this is systemd's name for the ethernet) and (rt1 (virbr0 (this is the bridge for windows). This never happened before as it has always been simply rt1.

So i look on DD-WRT and see this: *(MAC gets two ips, conflicts all around)*

[image: MAC gets two ips, conflicts all around]

I'm just trying to get back to my working config now and it's not happening.

Kubuntu shows no connections in network config, but if I run ifconfig I have all these broken duplicate connections that aren't in /etc/network/interfaces.

I noticed DD-WRT has two active connections for my nic, but if I look in DHCP clients only the working ip .127 will appear.
From DHCP clients I can erase the .127, this will make the name a * in active connections however .110 will still remain there.

I tried rebooting the router to no avail. Why are static IP's so cumbersome? I thought it was supposed to be simpler and more abolute than DHCP.

Comment: I'd look into using DHCP reservations instead. Reserve the address you want to assign to the device and remove any static IPs you may have assigned.